# Python3 Django project use the Python2 library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a project with Python 3.5.4, but I want to use a Python library called [pyghmi](https://github.com/openstack/pyghmi/blob/master/setup.cfg#L9), but the library only supports the Python 2.x.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: use `virtualenv` to create a python 2 virtual environment and then use that to execute the program requiring this lib

Comment: My project mainly use Python3. You say use `virtualenv` to create python2 virtual environment, how about my Python3 code?

Comment: You could fork `pyghmi` and make it python 3 compatible.

Comment: Interestingly, the tox.ini file suggests the tests get run against 3.5: https://github.com/openstack/pyghmi/blob/master/tox.ini#L2

Comment: @TomDalton Yes, its strange, in the CentOS, I use `python3 setup.py bdist_rpm` failed.

Answer (score 0):

The project was updated for python3 and is tested with python 3.5, though I will confess the vast majority of users are using python 2.7 at the moment.  The building of rpms, however, has not yet been tested for python3 (so far system python of centos 6 and centos7 has been the rpm environment).

I would be interested to know the issue you are hitting.

Comment: This is not an answer and will be deleted soon. [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)